# Set two paths to point to the same path

Tags: r, path, directory

I am sharing most of my codes with my colleague and in doing so we have different root directories we need to edit to run the code. For example, I am accessing all my files in:

```
   /usethis/mypath/mydir/now_same/mapk/
```

and he is in:

```
   /media/hispath/hisdir/now_same/mapk/
```

what I want to do is for any subsequent path directions to access any files/subroutines in the code, 
I want to point to my directory, i.e.(`/usethis/mypath/mydir/`) and without changing anything afterwards, i.e. (`/now_same/mapk/`). So if he sends me code with `/media/hispath/hisdir/now_same/mapk/`, I just want to use it without changing anything in the code.

How do we do it?

Comment: You could use `setwd()` to set the working directory to the appropriate path once. All pathes that appear in your script will then be understood relative to that path But this means, of course, that there is a single line of code that you need to change. If you are working on Linux, using soft links might be an option that might work without changes in the R code.

Comment: Can you do anything with normalizePath() ???

Answer (score 0):

Pass working director as argument, see example:

**myScript.R**

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
setwd(args[1])

# other code
# ...
# end of myScript.R
```

Now to run the script with custom working directory:

```
Rscript myScript.R path/to/my/directory
```